# Dynamic Comma Seperated string into different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

May someone please help me for this strange scenario. i have a data as given below.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
       (
       ID INT,
       PHONE001 VARCHAR(500)
       )
       INSERT TEST
      SELECT 1,'01323840261,01323844711' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2,'' UNION ALL
      SELECT  3,',01476862000' UNION ALL
      SELECT 4,'01233625418,1223822583,125985' UNION ALL
      SELECT 5,'2089840022,9.99021E+13'
```

and i am trying to put in seperate column for each comma value. the max number of column depends on the largest comma seperated string.

Expected Output

```
1|01323840261|01323844711|''
2|''|''|''
3|01476862000|''|''|
4|01233625418|1223822583|125985|
5|2089840022|9.99021E+13|''|
```

Comment: your question is not really clear. moreover, posted code and question makes little sense. clarify more as what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select id,T.c.value('t[1]','varchar(50)') as col1,
    T.c.value('t[2]','varchar(50)') as col2 ,
    T.c.value('t[3]','varchar(50)') as col3 from
     (select id,cast ('<t>'+ replace(PHONE001,',','</t><t>') +'</t>'
      as xml) x
        from @TABLE) a cross apply x.nodes('.') t(c)
```